# Trying to give "&" as part of adb shell input text

Tags: shell, android, input, adb

I'm working with the login page in one of the instance I need to pass the password which has "&" in it. It is not letting me send the text which involves "&".
Example:

```
adb shell input text vinod&tys
```

output:

> 'tys' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

The & is a special character in a command prompt and needs to be escaped.

In Windows command prompt, the escape character is `^`, which you can escape using `^` as well.

So the password would become `vinod^&tys` and `^` would become `^^`.

Comment: this works for string processing. However, when you send this as input text, it'll not work. Already tried ^ before raising the question

Comment: Always post everything you already tried.